# How to use intermediate result of Reads with another Reads

Tags: recycle-bin

The example I have is validating a credit card number string. The validations are 1) Issuer should exist for credit card number, and 2) Issuer should be an accepted one by merchant.

Here's work I have so far. Ideally, I would like to use the intermediate result `Issuer` from first Reads in the next reads. Is there a better way?

```
   Reads.filter[String](ValidationError("Invalid Issuer")) { cardNumber =>
      findIssuer(cardNumber).isDefined // Option[Issuer]
    } andThen
    Reads.filter[String](ValidationError("Issuer not accepted")) { cardNumber =>
// get issuer, then check issuer is accepted by merchant
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer, but you might consider to write this logic as `for/yield` expression:

```
val result: Either[String, Issuer] = for {
  card <- json.validate[Card].asEither.leftMap(_ => "Reading error")
  issuer <- findIssuer(card.number) //returns Either[String, _]
  _ <- isAccepted(issuer) // returns Either[String,_]
} yield issuer
```

P.S. It's a gateway case to start using scalaz `Validation`.

Comment: Thanks. I think Reads.apply will also work, and didn't make the connection between JsError and ValidationResult. Ex.     Reads { jsValue =>
      jsValue.validate[String] match {
        case JsSuccess(cardNumber, _) =>
          val optIssuer = inferIssuer(cardNumber)
          optIssuer match {
            case Some(issuer) =>
              // check if issuer is accepted by merchant
              ???
            case None =>
              JsError("Invalid Issuer")
          }
        case err: JsError =>
          err
      }
    }

Comment: @ferk86 `issuer` is under another function scope and is not accessible in the second function, so you need some spaghetti solution - hope somebody will provide it here.